# fdb always starts in IE

Tags: apache-flex, fdb

I don't known what happened but fdb.exe now always start debug swf in IE
And IE not my default browser!

How to return its default behaiviuor? (embeded browser only with swf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Flex Builder or Flash Builder?

If so, go to Window > Properties > General > Web Browser and click new.  You will then need to add the path to your browser and its name.

Select the browser you added and it should work.

For some reason eclipse doesn't like to launch the actual default browser sometimes and you have to manually specify it.

Comment: i use fdb from console but get it from flex3 tools, and I solve trouble getting flashplayer_10_sa_debug.exe from adobe site. But thank you for your reply.